# get_post_galleries_images returning empty array

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a custom theme in Wordpress and want to get all images gallery which are in a post with a title of 'aaa'. I tried this:

```
<?php
 $post= get_page_by_title('aaa', OBJECT, 'post');

// Make sure the post has a gallery in it
if( $post )
   {
    // Retrieve the first gallery in the post
    $gallery =  get_post_galleries_images( $post->ID ); 
    echo '<ul>';
    if(empty($gallery))
        echo "Empty gallery $post->ID";
    // Loop through each image in each gallery
    foreach( $gallery as $image_url ) {
        echo '<li>' . '<img src="' . $image_url . '">' . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';



  }


?>
```

But the resultant output is

  Empty gallery 348

348 is post ID of the 'aaa' post. This means that the gallery is there in the 'aaa' post but it's empty, which is not true. My gallery contains 5 images.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this quickly and it's clear that the function does NOT work for galleries created using the block editor.  It does work for galleries created with the old classic editor.  There is a WP trac bug report for it, but as yet not fixed in core. https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/43826.

Check in your phpmyadmin, they are stored differently.

```
<p>[gallery ids="30,23,22"]</p>
```

VS

```
<!-- wp:gallery {"ids":[34,32,27]} -->
```

Comment: Consider writing your little search on the post content for now? or wait till wp 5.2 hopefully sorted then.